# Binary Tree hasPathSum() Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

Hi 
I am trying to implement `hasPathSum()`
means for given number is there any path exist between root-to-leaf node.

I got this code from Stanford website. And i am thinking this is wrong

```
/** 
 Given a tree and a sum, returns true if there is a path from the root 
 down to a leaf, such that adding up all the values along the path 
 equals the given sum. 
 Strategy: subtract the node value from the sum when recurring down, 
 and check to see if the sum is 0 when you run out of tree. 
*/ 

boolean hasPathSum(Node node, int sum) { 
  // return true if we run out of tree and sum==0 
  if (node == null){ 
    return(sum == 0); 
  } 
  else { 
  // otherwise check both subtrees 
    int subSum = sum - node.data; 
    return(hasPathSum(node.left, subSum) || hasPathSum(node.right, subSum)); 
  }
```

Is this a right implementation?

I am thinking this **if** should be

- **if(node.left==null && node.right==null)**

If i am wrong Please clear my confusion

consider this case:

```
          5
         / \
        2   1
       /    
      3
```

-Thanks

Comment: Why not test it and find out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should just code it and try it - you learn a lot that way. (*Edit: I certainly am ...*)

I believe the original code fails for `hasPathSum(tree, 7)` because node 2 is not a leaf.

**Edit:**

Original code withdrawn due to obvious mistakes - obvious at least to everyone but me :-)

**Edit:**

My new solution is below.  Note that the included optimization (`if (sum <= node.data)`) *assumes the tree is made up of all **positive** data values*. It should be removed or tweaked if the tree has zero or negative data values. (thanks @Mark Peters).

Also note the discussion in the answer comments about handling `hasPathSum(null, 0)`.

```
static boolean hasPathSumBert(final Node node, final int sum) {
    // return true if we run out of tree and sum==0
    if (node == null) {                                   // empty tree
        // choose one:
        return (sum == 0);
        //return false;
    } else if (node.left == null && node.right == null) { // leaf
        return (sum == node.data);
    } else if (sum <= node.data) {                        // sum used up
        return false;
    } else {                                              // try children
        return (node.left != null  && hasPathSumBert(node.left, sum - node.data)) ||
               (node.right != null && hasPathSumBert(node.right, sum - node.data));
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
public class TreeTest {
    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        Node(final int data, final Node left, final Node right) {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Node three = new Node(3, null, null);

        final Node two = new Node(2, three, null);
        final Node one = new Node(1, null, null);

        final Node five = new Node(5, two, one);
        final Node tree = five;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "");
            System.out.println("original = " + hasPathSum(tree, i));
            System.out.println("bert     = " + hasPathSumBert(tree, i));
            System.out.println("mark     = " + hasPathSumMark(tree, i));
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("hasPathSumBert(null, 0): "+ hasPathSumBert(null, 0));
        System.out.println("hasPathSumBert(null, 1): "+ hasPathSumBert(null, 1));
    }

    static boolean hasPathSum(final Node node, final int sum) {
        // return true if we run out of tree and sum==0
        if (node == null) {
            return (sum == 0);
        } else {
            // otherwise check both subtrees
            final int subSum = sum - node.data;
            return (hasPathSum(node.left, subSum) || hasPathSum(node.right, subSum));
        }
    }

    static boolean hasPathSumBert(final Node node, final int sum) {
        // return true if we run out of tree and sum==0
        if (node == null) {                                   // empty tree
            // choose one:
            return (sum == 0);
            //return false;
        } else if (node.left == null && node.right == null) { // leaf
            return (sum == node.data);
        } else if (sum <= node.data) {                        // sum used up
            return false;
        } else {                                              // try children
            return (node.left != null  && hasPathSumBert(node.left, sum - node.data)) ||
                   (node.right != null && hasPathSumBert(node.right, sum - node.data));
        }
    }

    static boolean hasPathSumMark(final Node node, final int sum) {
        final int subSum = sum - node.data;
        if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
            return (subSum == 0);
        } else {
            // otherwise check both subtrees
            if (node.left != null  && hasPathSumMark(node.left, subSum))
                return true;
            if (node.right != null && hasPathSumMark(node.right, subSum))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample run: (Note case 7)

```
0
original = false
bert     = false
mark     = false

1
original = false
bert     = false
mark     = false

2
original = false
bert     = false
mark     = false

3
original = false
bert     = false
mark     = false

4
original = false
bert     = false
mark     = false

5
original = false
bert     = false
mark     = false

6
original = true
bert     = true
mark     = true

7
original = true
bert     = false
mark     = false

8
original = false
bert     = false
mark     = false

9
original = false
bert     = false
mark     = false

10
original = true
bert     = true
mark     = true

hasPathSumBert(null, 0): true
hasPathSumBert(null, 1): false
```

Comment: Yes, everybody's missing the fact that the original solution considers a node with one child a "leaf".  But your correction is completely wrong.  Your first correction requires **all paths to leaves** to have the correct sum, which isn't the requirement.  Your second alternative is really messed up, but the idea should work.

Comment: No correction is necessary.  The original code is correct.  It is irrelevant whether any given node is a leaf, the termination condition of the recursion is that node == null, which is only ever satisfied when a path reaches _past_ a leaf.

Comment: @mokus, wrong, it terminates when ONE of the children is null.  Meaning in the OP's example `hasPathSum(root, 7)` will return true when it shouldn't.  Unfortunately I can't fix the votes until the answer is fixed.  The first correction is still completely wrong, and the second one needs bette null handling for when one of the children is null but not the other.

Comment: @Mark Peters: I see, you're referring to the suggested modification in the answer.  I'm stating that there is no modification required in the first place:  the quoted code is correct as-is.

Comment: @mokus: No, it's not.  And I **am** talking about the original solution posted by the OP.  Run it and see.  Or consider a tree with root `5` and one left node `1` and what happens when you call `hasPathSum(root, 5)`.

Comment: Next time I'll code before I answer :-).  I screwed the pooch on this answer.  First off, are we in agreement that leaves are only nodes with no children?

Comment: @Bert: yes, though apparently nobody else is :-).

Comment: @Mark Peters: ah, nevermind - I see what you're getting at.  It considers the '2' to have an (existent but) empty right subtree.

Comment: @Mark Peters: sorry, thought more about that and edited that line from my comment, didn't see your reply at that point or I would've left it.

Comment: It sounds like we agree that (1) "leaf means only nodes with no children" and (2) "hasPathSum(root, 7) is a valid test that fails - a correct solution should return false but the original code will return true"

Comment: @Mark Peters: I guess my thought process on that is an extension of the idea that an empty subtree _does_ have a path of length zero from root to leaf.  The reason I thought of it as a specification problem is that the difference is whether the '2' node has an empty left subtree or does not have a left subtree at all.  Which is not specified.

Comment: @mokus: That might be, but the spec doesn't ask you to look at what the *subtrees* have, they ask you to look at the the tree as a whole.  So your reasoning should apply to a case where the *caller* passes an empty tree (`node == null`), but not to any subtrees.  For all the specification cares, the implementation isn't even recursive.

Comment: @myself: re: the idea that an empty subtree does have a path of length zero.  This idea itself even seems to be unnatural on reflection.  "Has a path" is an existentially quantified property, and the default case for existential quantification ought to be `false`, just as the default case for universal quantification is generally taken to be `true`.  I think this is probably the root of the error itself.  In other words, it shouln't even be the case that an empty tree "has a path such that ...", because it just doesn't even have a path.

Comment: @Mark Peters: Yea, I wasn't saying I was right to think that - after all, I was in the process of retracting it when you replied to it ;)

Comment: Despite @mokus' very reasonable rationale that `hasPathSum(null, 0)` should return false`, I still think my first instinct is that `hasPathSum(null, 0)` should return true`. Regardless, the behavior for an empty tree is clearly a special case that should be clearly specified/documented.

Comment: @Bert F: My inclination would be that it should be documented, but the specification should just be "passing a null tree to hasPathSum results in undefined behaviour", or perhaps "passing a null tree to hasPathSum results in an IllegalArgumentException/NPE being thrown".  Leave the existentialist musings to the caller of your library.

Comment: By the way I like your performance improving shortcut, `else if (sum <= node.data)`, since it may prune much of the search tree.  But keep in mind it will only work if it is guaranteed that all nodes have a positive value (it is incorrect when 0 or negative numbers are allowed).

Comment: @Mark Peters - very good points on both and I find I'm forced to agree on both points #1 - Using IAE/NPE bothers me, but I see no better solution. #2 - I'm editing the response to note the assumption about positive numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Since Bert isn't fixing his answer, I'll post the correct one.

Yes, you're right that the original code is broken, despite what most people here are saying.  In your example

```
      5
     / \
    2   1
   /    
  3
```

Calling

```
hasPathSum(root, 7);
```

will return `true` despite the fact that there is no root-to-leaf path that adds to 7.  That's because when node `2` is reached, it recursively checks the right child (with sum 0), which then returns true because the right child is `null`.

The fix is inspired by Bert's answer:

```
// `if` statement should check children and `return` statement deduct node.data from sum
boolean hasPathSum(Node node, int sum) { 
  int subSum = sum - node.data; 
  if(node.left==null && node.right==null) { 
    return(subSum == 0); 
  } 
  else { 
    // otherwise check both subtrees 
    if ( node.left != null && hasPathSum(node.left, subSum) ) {
        return true;
    if ( node.right != null && hasPathSum(node.right, subSum) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  } 
}
```

You can roll the else block into one long statement if you want (lots of ands and ors), but I find this cleaner.

Comment: Thanks Mark - I was working on something, but I'm trying to do too many things at once. The only other thing to consider is that this solution doesn't handle an empty tree (node == null).

Comment: That's true, I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader if they think it should.

Comment: Thanks mark for the clear solution, I have used it here - http://k2code.blogspot.in/2011/05/root-to-leaf-path.html.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys 
Thanks for your answers, this discussion seems very intersting,
last night again i tried to implement this function and   i think my solution will work for all cases,

actually I implemented in simpler way so that it can be understandable by everyone

---

**There are four cases to check**

1. if both childs are null (our targeted case)
2. if only right child exists (means left child is null)
3. if only left child exists (means right child is null)
4. if both childs exists (means node is having left and right childs)

**One special case**: if you pass input tree directly as null then it is required to handle (one more if block req.)

```
    public static boolean hasPathSum(TNode root, int sum)
{
    if(root==null) //it is called only if you pass directly null
    return false;

    int subsum = sum-root.data;
    //if(subsum<0) return false; //uncomment this for reducing calls for negative numbers
    if(root.left==null && root.right==null) //for leaf node
    return (subsum==0);

    if(root.left==null) //if only right child exist
    return hasPathSum(root.right, subsum);

    if(root.right==null)//if only left child exist
    return hasPathSum(root.left, subsum);

    return (hasPathSum(root.left, subsum) || hasPathSum(root.right,subsum));
}
```

Please review my code 
will this work for all the binary tree cases? and 
let me know if any changes are required.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OP's function clearly fails for the following simple case:

```
   1
    \
     2
```

The above tree as just one root to leaf path of sum `3`. But OP's function will return true for `hasPathSum(root,1)`

This happens because *the changing sub-sum should be compared to zero only when we reach a leaf node(empty left sub-tree and empty right sub-tree) or a special case of an empty tree.*

OP's function is treating any node with `NULL` child as leaf.

The following function( which is same as Mark's + one additional check) fixes it:

```
boolean hasPathSum(Node node, int sum) {
        // CASE 1: empty tree.
        if (node == NULL) {
                return sum == 0;
        }
        // CASE 2: Tree exits.
        int subSum = sum - node.data;
        // CASE 2A: Function is called on a leaf node.
        if (node.left==null && node.right==null) {
                return subSum == 0;
        // CASE 2B: Function is called on a non-leaf node.
        } else {
                // CASE 2BA: Non-left node has desired path in left subtree.
                if (node.left != null && hasPathSum(node.left, subSum) ){
                        return true;
                }
                // CASE 2BB: Non-left node has desired path in right subtree.
                if ( node.right != null && hasPathSum(node.right, subSum) ) {
                        return true;
                }
                // CASE 2BC: Non-left node has no desired pat.
                return false;
        }
}
```

C version: [Ideone Link](http://www.ideone.com/OiE5I)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach that calculates the sum of each path, and matches it to the target value. IMHO, this seems more intuitive than using the logic of subsums.

Additionally, the nums list would store all root-to-leaf paths sums. I added this just to make sure that my code wasn't generating any unwanted paths.

```
public static boolean hasPathSum(Node root, int sum, int val, ArrayList<Integer> nums) {
    if(root == null) {
        return (sum == 0);
    }

    val = val + root.data;

    if(root.right == null && root.left == null) {
        nums.add(val);
        return (val == sum);
    }

    boolean left = hasPathSum(root.left, sum, val, nums);
    boolean right = hasPathSum(root.right, sum, val, nums);

    return left || right;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   bool hasPathSum(struct node* node, int sum){
        if(node == NULL){       
           return false;  
        }
        if((sum - (node->data) == 0) && (node->left == NULL) && (node->right == NULL) ) {    
            return true;  
        }
        if (sum - (node->data) < 0)  { 
            return false;  
        } else {       
            return( hasPathSum (node->left,sum - ( node->data ) ) || hasPathSum (node->right, sum - (node->data) ) );  
        }
   }
```